# Image slider positioning

Tags: jquery, image, slider, carousel

I am looking for some advice/support on an image slider which I have created. Its made of two parts, the images that slide on the left and the captions and navigation to the right. the Issue I am facing is that I cannot get the captions out of the container of the slide itself I am wondering if there is a way to escape the caption out and still work with the slide when it changes.

Another problem is around the responsiveness on a large screen its terrible and I just need some advice. Here is a fiddle I have created and its a replica.

https://jsfiddle.net/df2psx6q/

Here is the JQuery:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

The HTML:

```
<section class="slider-content" style="position: relative;">
<div class="box-slider right-skew-slider"></div>
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/ink-cloud.jpg" alt="Digital Icon">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/ink-cloud.jpg" alt="Digital Icon">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/ink-cloud.jpg" alt="Digital Icon">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center" class="controls">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
</section>
```